# How can I make transfers using Google Data Transfer API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-ruby-client

I'm writing a piece of code in Ruby for making data transfers using Google Data Transfer API. I specifically mean [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers/insert)

The code I have is as follows:

```
idOldUser = "116170568974079979335"
idNewUser = "105318746921076261308"

atp = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::ApplicationTransferParam.new(
    key: "PRIVACY_LEVEL",
    value: ["PRIVATE", "SHARED"])

appid =  435070579839 
adt = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::ApplicationDataTransfer.new(
    application_id: appid,
    application_transfer_params: [atp])

dt = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::DataTransfer.new(
    kind: "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
    old_owner_user_id: idOldUser,
    new_owner_user_id: idNewUser,
    application_data_transfers: [adt])

service = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::DataTransferService.new
service.insert_transfer(dt)
```

When I execute it, the following error appears:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.23.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:212:in `check_status': Unauthorized (Google::Apis::AuthorizationError)
from /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.23.4/lib/google/apis/core/api_command.rb:118:in `check_status'
from /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client-0.23.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:183:in `process_response'
```

I've also tried to execute it from API Explorer. The following JSON returns a  HTTP 200. Some minutes after that, I see in the new user's inbox a mail saying that the transfer is completed. Then I see in Calendar app an entry called "Transfered from user". However, it appears empty.

```
{
  "oldOwnerUserId": "116170568974079979335",
  "newOwnerUserId": "105318746921076261308",
  "kind": "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
  "applicationDataTransfers": [
    {
      "applicationId": "435070579839",
      "applicationTransferParams": [
        {
          "key": "PRIVACY_LEVEL",
          "value": [
            "PRIVATE",
            "SHARED"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used this scope:    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.datatransfer

And curiously, the other methods of that library, such as list_applications, work for me. The only problem is with insert_transfer .

Can you help me to make this data transfer working? If it's possible with Ruby, great.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. I had to refresh the token before calling insert_transfer.

So the working code is as follows:

```
idOldUser = "116170568974079979335"
idNewUser = "105318746921076261308"

atp = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::ApplicationTransferParam.new(
    key: "PRIVACY_LEVEL",
    value: ["PRIVATE", "SHARED"])

appid =  435070579839 
adt = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::ApplicationDataTransfer.new(
    application_id: appid,
    application_transfer_params: [atp])

dt = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::DataTransfer.new(
    kind: "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
    old_owner_user_id: idOldUser,
    new_owner_user_id: idNewUser,
    application_data_transfers: [adt])

service = Google::Apis::AdminDatatransferV1::DataTransferService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize
service.insert_transfer(dt)
```

On the other hand, the order of the fields on the JSON we send matters. So if we change their order, we can receive a HTTP 200 response, while the data transfer will never be performed. That's why the JSON I was sending from API Explorer was not working.